How can I use react-papaparse to parse a CSV file in the same directory as my react app
I have a React project (I'm new to React) with a directory named "csvData" containing 3 CSVs. I need to parse those CSVs and found out that react-papaparse could do that. But the documentation only shows examples to parse a csv from a local file with a "Browse file" button: https://react-papaparse.js.org/docs#local-files.
I think what I need is simpler than the demo proposed but I don't see how to adapt it.
